# How can I download android android sdk r12

Tags: android, sdk

On the official page I see the android-sdk_r16-linux.tgz but I can not found some lower versions from the android skd. Any ideas how can I download some lower version ?

Comment: +1: I think this is a valid question, especially since the SDK Tools (not the API) change behavior all the time and most of the changes are not documented.

Comment: exactly that is my problem, I have a custom build script that  doesn't works just because the sdk is changed and in some places it is no backward compatible, at least in my case appears to have a lot of problems with the latest sdk. I wanted to install older sdk on my fresh install of linux just because of this problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK download is just a starter kit, actual platform is downloaded from the Android SDK manager in Eclipse. You can download the version you want by choosing the appropriate checkbox[image]

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why you would want to do this (bug fixes and improvement happen with newer releases and you wont be able to build to a target of Android 3.0+), but:

Windows: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r12-windows.exe

Linux: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r12-linux_x86.tgz

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r14-linux.tgz
(the oldest I can find is r12)

OSX: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r14-macosx.zip
(oldest I found is r14)

So, hopefully you are using Windows and then you're in luck.

Hope that helps! Really, though, I would reconsider your motivation to use an outdated plugin.

Comment: I too need an older SDK version.  Actually I need an older version of the SDK Tools (not the SDK per se)... The reason is, the stuff I'm working on have depended on the tools to behave a certain way. On the newer SDK tools, my stuff breaks....  Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to TryTryAgain's lead, I was able to find the right filename for the r12 SDK for linux:

http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r12-linux_x86.tgz